# If $X,Y \sim \mathscr P(\lambda)$ and $X+Y \sim \mathscr P(2\lambda)$, are $X$ and $Y$ independent?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, independence, poisson-distribution

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables that follow the Poisson distribution $\mathscr P(\lambda)$ (with $\lambda > 0$).

It is well-known that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent then the random variable $X+Y$ follows the Poisson distribution $\mathscr P(2\lambda)$ (by direct computations).

Is the converse true ? If $X+Y$ follows the Poisson distribution $\mathscr P(2\lambda)$, are $X$ and $Y$ necessarily independent?

Comment: No. Fix the probability masses at $\max(X,Y)\geq 4$ and now how many (independent) equations are there governing the masses at $(X,Y)\in\{0,1,2,3\}^2$?

Comment: @user10354138 What do you mean by "fix the probability masses at $\max(X,Y)\geq 4$" ?

Comment: I mean let the joint pmf of $X,Y$ be the same as the independent case for all but the 16 probability masses at $X,Y\in\{0,1,2,3\}$, and check there are not 16 independent linear equations just from the marginal pmfs $X, Y, X+Y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Consider $r(01)=-r(02)=r(12)=-r(21)=r(20)=-r(10)=\epsilon$ and $r(ij)=0$ outside. If $p_i=e^{-\alpha}\alpha^i/i!$ then $(p_ip_j+r(ij))$ is a counter example if $\epsilon$ is small enough.

Comment: Thanks it works !